# CSS Select List that 'drops' to the right

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm working in MVC4 and want to have a DropDownList that 'drops' to the right, instead of down.

http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/

The demo above shows the style that I'm looking for. However, instead of dropping down, I want it to be to the right.

Like this:
[image]

I know that the link above uses an ul/li, but if I could bind this to use DropDownListFor, that would be ideal.

Comment: Don't expect someone to reverse-engineer the example. You should provide your own example code as part of the question.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the device isn't wide enough to display your fly-out list?

Comment: The section will be wide enough to accommodate this style. It's not responsive to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use DropDownListFor as usual. The only thing you should do is call jQuery's extension method on a dropdown of interest. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dorpdownId').dropdown();
});
```

Actually [the article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/) has well written documentation.